# Can't access docker container on localhost:8080

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

So I was trying to build a docker image for a simple typescript application, I was able to build and run the image successfully but I am unable to access the endpoints to the port binded on my localhost,
here are all the images for reference, I can't seem to be able to debug the error.
note here i have setup 2 images separately one on localhost and another on 0.0.0.0 still can't access any of them.

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install typescript

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

docker ps result:

CONTAINERID          IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES


2f974d0daf2a        srinchow/test_server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   36 minutes ago      Up 36 minutes       127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp   vigorous_cannon


55c32614ee44        srinchow/test_server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:49160->8080/tcp    peaceful_chandrasekhar

docker inspect result:

"NetworkSettings": {
"Bridge": "",
"SandboxID": "7654c9a018abf4718ece4fa878d8a2a1e92d9c5662be55475b45443f946da6d2",
"HairpinMode": false,
"LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
"LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"Ports": {
"8080/tcp": [
{
"HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
"HostPort": "8080"
}
]
},
"SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7654c9a018ab",
"SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
"SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
"EndpointID": "e7fecc80a696f8ccec52b81cd82ed45fef4bc44ff88bfc5b68b9cdf56af17c84",
"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
"IPPrefixLen": 16,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
"Networks": {
"bridge": {
"IPAMConfig": null,
"Links": null,
"Aliases": null,
"NetworkID": "36a6859b6bfaed9af4118bfb4ff09c7b3be2fc799f57972b7f135c48c20cc5d2",
"EndpointID": "e7fecc80a696f8ccec52b81cd82ed45fef4bc44ff88bfc5b68b9cdf56af17c84",
"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
"IPPrefixLen": 16,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
"DriverOpts": null
}
}
}
}
]

Comment: Please share your dockerfile?

Comment: Show more codes in question?I cann't open the link showed. Intuitive feeling,may be some error use about localhost and container's internal Ip,or the port exposed?

Comment: @DashrathMundkar i have attached my dockerfile as an image

Comment: @bigpang ill add the code here as well seems like the image link is broken somehow

Comment: Do not share code, commands and errors in images. In most cases it is not readable and it impairs the search engine hability to index them. This is pointed out as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Also, can you please edit your question and format it correctly, more specifically the code blocks ? Look for help on the editor commands and on the right side of the screen while editing.

Comment: @Srin Chow  Show the command that you start the container. Do you use  `-p` parameter?In my thoughts,if you run the ndoe by binding on 0.0.0.0:8080,then ,I just only        think about the `-p`parameter.

Comment: @bigpangl the command i used was . sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 --name gg d7f38f573373

Comment: If you do as you say , I do not know why.Never happened to me like you got.